# SQL Query result: no value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, sql

this is my SQL query

```
    string SqlStr = string.Format("
insert into Sales(date_,tsale,order_id,quant,crd_typ,client_id)
    values(#{0}#,'{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},{5})", s.Date,s.Tsale,s.OrderId, s.Quant, s.CrdTyp, s.ClientId);
```

in WinForm date_ is DateTime , crd_typ is string and the rest are int.

in Access  date_ is Data/Time, crd_typ is string and the rest are int.

(int Access order_id is key)
what is wrong?

Comment: already wrote in the title @3615

Comment: How do you execute the statement? When I created a c# win form app in order to maintain data in a SQL DB, I needed to define the statement with @ placeholders, then create a SQL command with the statement and afterwards add the parameters (stmt.parameter.addwithvalue or something like this)... don't know if this is generally required, but it was the only way I made my prog working.

Comment: And what is `s`?  Your query makes no sense.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Your int's should not have single quotes around them, your strings should.  I think you have quotes around the int's, and none around your string (crd_type).

Comment: Items 0, 4 & 5 are missing the single quotes.

Comment: @MichaelGorsich got it good, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not construct queries with `String.Format` but use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection.

For your problem:

You say you have one `DateTime` and one `String` in your datatable. Nonetheless, your query has one `DateTime` and three `String` parameters. So at least two `int` values are given as `String`. Could be a problem. You can solve this by using parameterized queries.

A second possibiliy could be, that your string may contain a `'` character. Thus, your query parsing may be stopped before the query is finished. You can prevent this with parameterized queries.

You see, you **should really**  use parameterized queries. Many problems will solve themselves this way.